# What is a good way to change fields in livecycle-documents without triggering validations?

Tags: javascript, xml, validation, livecycle-designer, adobe-javascript

I got a form with lots of fields and many scripts so I broke it down to my very fundamental problem with this example:

[image: Example Form]

Before printing I check if everything is filled out with:

```
Seite1.execValidate();
```

The validate XML source of the field:

```
<validate nullTest="error" scriptTest="error"/>
```

When clicking on the top-button I want different things to happen. 
For example:

```
field.rawValue  =   "";
```

or (if it's a decimal field)

```
//isPauschal was set earlier to either true or false
field.value.decimal.leadDigits  =   (isPauschal)?"4":"2";
```

But then this happens:

[image: Field goes blue (=it is empty) when setting its Value to "" - this I want only to happen when I'm validating with the print-button]

Field goes blue (=it is empty) when setting its value to "" - this I want only to happen when I'm validating with the print-button.
Now I found a workaround:

```
field.mandatory =   "";
field.rawValue  =   "";
field.mandatory =   "error";
```

But if I were to write this every time I changed something that would trigger this my code would look pretty bad and much more confusing.

Can someone help me?
What could I do to easily validate my fields before printing and still being able to change them around with js at runtime without them making strange colors. ;) 
I don't want to validate them individually - I wish to keep something like the execValidate() command so it automatically checks all the fields in a subform.

Let me know if you need any more information!